# izpack install jar works only in a folder starting with "izpack"

Tags: maven, izpack

I'm using Maven and the izpack-maven-plugin for one of my java project.

My izpack files are in ${basedir}/izpack.

My install.xml file is in ${basedir}/src/main/filter and is filtered during the package phase

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/filter</directory>
        <targetPath>${basedir}/izpack</targetPath>
        <includes>
            <include>install.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

The plugin in the pluginManagement

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-beta6</version>
</plugin>
```

The plugin in the build

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <installFile>${basedir}/izpack/install.xml</installFile>
        <baseDir>${basedir}/izpack</baseDir>
        <installerType>standard</installerType>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My install.xml file is quit simple (only one pack gathering 3 jars)

When I run the goal izpack:izpack, everything looks fine.

The problem is that the generated install jar can only be run when it is in a folder which name starts with "izpack".
Case 1 : jar not in a "izpack*" folder
- double click does nothing
- java - jar returns this

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.IzPackException: com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.MergeException: Could not find class TargetPanel : Current classpath is at com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.InstallerGui$1.run(InstallerGui.java:57)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.MergeException: Could not find class TargetPanel : Current classpath is
        at com.izforge.izpack.merge.resolve.ClassPathCrawler.searchClassInClassPath(ClassPathCrawler.java:125)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.manager.PanelManager.loadPanelsInContainer(PanelManager.java:72)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.base.InstallerController.preloadInstaller(InstallerController.java:30)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.InstallerGui$1.run(InstallerGui.java:50)
        ... 8 more
```

Case 2 : jar in a "izpack*" folder
- double click runs normaly

Any idea ?

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue. (Thank you again Raghuram to show me the way)

I use the 1.0-alpha-5 version

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-5</version>
</plugin>
```

The attributes used by the plugins have to be changed

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- For 1.0-alpha-5 version -->
        <installerFile>${basedir}/target/${project.name}</installerFile>
        <izpackBasedir>${basedir}/izpack</izpackBasedir>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>izpack</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>izpack</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you be hitting [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/IZPACK-627) open izpack bug?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find this issue.

Comment: There is a workaroud : using the 1.0-alpha-5 version of the plugin. But the configuration sshould then use the following attributes : <installerFile>, <izpackBasedir> and <kind>.  But, I hav,'t found yet, a way to name the generated jar, and move it to ${basedir}/target. For the moment, it is ${basedir}/izpack/install.xml.jar